# What difference does it make who my ministers are?

Tags: tropico-4

After building a ministry, I'm allowed to pick who I want to take the various ministry positions.  Each candidate has three attributes listed, with a ranking from terrible to excellent (or something like that).

What difference does my choice make?  Are certain edicts more or less effective based on the attributes of the corresponding minister?  There doesn't seem to be any feedback.

Comment: the only feedback I got so far was that one of them made a huge blunder (it was the education minister), and caused some intellectuals to leave the island.  Also, my defense minister died at some point, he was my best minister with above average to exceptional in all categories :(

Comment: It might improve the frequency that they save enough coupons for a free building.

Comment: The only feedback I got is that one killed a whole gang with one bullet so crime went down.

Comment: So maybe there are various random events for each ministry, and their attributes help decide the chances of triggering a good or bad event?

Comment: That sounds probable to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the manual:

> Depending on their Leadership, Courage and Intelligence attributes, your Ministers may generate positive or negative events. A competent Minister will make your life easier while an incompetent one will force you to fire him or suffer the the consequences of his mistakes.

The in-game description of the Council of Ministers lines up with this too:

> If your ministers are stupid, cowardly and all-around bad leaders, expect many gaffes, which will brighten the day of Tropico News Today.

In other words, it's more likely that ministers with higher stats will give foreign leaders impromptu rock concerts, save up for free buildings, and kill entire gangs, yielding nice bonuses; while it's more likely that ministers with lower stats will end up flying their laundry on flag poles, calling Europe a US state, and attacking foreign leaders with forks, resulting in negative effects unless you fire them.

Comment: interesting, my education minister had excellent in the first 2 stats but was terrible in leadership, yet he turned out to be useless, what a shame.  I would think intelligence was more useful for a education minster than leadership :(

Comment: Is the manual available online anywhere?  I can't find a link to it from Steam.

Comment: @bwarner: Not that I know of, but it's in the install folder with the retail version as a .pdf.

Comment: The manual is available here:
http://store.steampowered.com/manual/57690/?l=english&cc=AU&os=windows

Comment: @yx. -- High intelligence/courage, low leadership means she had great ideas and the initiative to try to enact them, but *sucked* at getting people organized to actually make them work.

Comment: Personally if I'm forced to pick two out of three, I go for high int/leadership, low courage -- meaning less events but a much higher chance of said events being beneficial.